# linux command "file" shows "for GNU/Linux 2.6.24"

Tags: linux, file

I always use the `file` command to check the file type, mostly after I compile a new project to make sure everything is fine.

The output is something similar to this below:

```
proj_out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x23d9f966854e09d721c6110d505247483dae02fe, stripped
```

My question is since my Linux Kernel is updated to 3.0+, why does it still shows it is compiled for older versions of Linux?

```
for GNU/Linux 2.6.24
```

Is it anything related to `file` command or do I have to do anything to compile my project against newer Linux Kernel?

Thanks

Comment: What version of the Linux headers are in `/usr/src/linux`?

Comment: The output of the compiler doesn't depend on the kernel version you're using. It solely depends on the compiler you're using.

Comment: It seems I have different versions of linux here:

mahdi@XO0PS:~$ ls /usr/src/ | grep linux
linux-headers-2.6.38-14
linux-headers-2.6.38-14-generic-pae
linux-headers-2.6.38-8
linux-headers-3.2.0-23
linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-24
linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-26
linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-27
linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic
linux-headers-3.2.0-29
linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic

Comment: H2CO3

I know what you mean. But I have faced different outputs of this command when I compile my porject on different machines with different kernels. So, What does this `for GNU/Linux 2.6.24` mean anyway?

Comment: did you get the solution @MahdiSadeghi . I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The kernel version displayed by *file* on an executable has nothing to do with the kernel installed on your system. It matches the C library the program was linked with at build time.

Your C compiler targets a specific C library (usually glibc). In turn, the C library targets a kernel API (i.e. the C library is built for a specific kernel). That is the version displayed by *file*.

You don't have to worry about the mimatch between the kernel version displayed by *file* and the kernel version installed on your machine.

@REALFREE: you can try the following experiment. Maybe it will
help you get a grasp of what's going on:

```
$ uname -r
3.10-2-amd64
$ gcc -Wall -Werror hello.c -o hello
$ readelf --notes ./hello
Displaying notes found at file offset 0x0000021c with length 0x00000020:
  Owner                 Data size       Description
  GNU                  0x00000010       NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (ABI version tag)
    OS: Linux, ABI: 2.6.32
```

The information about the *ABI tag* is contained in an elf
segment called *NOTE*. This information is written by the linker
when the program is compiled. It matches the ABI tag of the C library.

```
$ ldd ./hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffd31fe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5f1a465000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5f1a827000)
$ readelf --notes /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Displaying notes found at file offset 0x00000294 with length 0x00000020:
  Propriétaire        Taille des données        Description
  GNU                  0x00000010       NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (étiquette de version ABI)
    OS: Linux, ABI: 2.6.32
```

In order to build the C library, you have to select a kernel
version. Here, the C library was compiled for a 2.6.32 kernel but
it also works with more recent kernels. However, if the program
is run on a kernel older than 2.6.32, a *kernel too old* warning
is displayed.

Comment: I was wondering why they are different? I came across the same situation that compiled file uses 2.6.24 but kernel version installed on the machine is 3.2.0-52

Answer (score 3):

That version number refers to the kernel headers from which the glibc C library was built on the host that the compiler was run on.  Broadly, it shows the level of kernel that the executable will be expected to support.

Comment: Thanks. So it is related to the libraries I use in my project and I don't have anything to change here.