# Specify the expected Linux version of the output binary of GCC

Tags: linux, gcc, version

I'm helping others doing a lab experiment of the "operating systems concepts" course. The experiment task is to compile **Linux 2.6.26** and run it in QEMU.

After compiling the Linux kernel, we're told to write a smallest program to serve as the `init` program. The example we're presented (and we followed) is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while (1) {
        puts("Hello!");
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

The compilation command is:

```sh
root@ubuntu:/home/vmware/oslab# gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@ubuntu:/home/vmware/oslab# gcc -static -o init hello.c
```

The host environment should be a freshly-installed Ubuntu 14.04.6 (i386).

---

The problem is, one of my fellow students followed the instruction carefully, and the init program failed to execute. I asked him for his whole `initrd.img`, and noticed how his `init` program looks different:

```
vmware@ubuntu:~/oslab$ file mnt/init
mnt/init: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=7365ac494ef1d924c171899c169dbd3195d2d209, not stripped
```

To me, that's clearly not something that can run on Linux 2.6.26. With GCC 4.8 provided in the Ubuntu APT repository (trusty), how can I get GCC to output something that runs on Linux 2.6.26?

FYI: On my own testing VM (also Ubuntu 14.04.6, Linux 4.4, same latest GCC version from Ubuntu APT repo as of April 2, 2019), the compiled program shows ***Linux 2.6.24*** in `file` output. Also, *his* binary runs perfectly well in QEMU with my freshly compiled 2.6.32.37 kernel.

Comment: It's a glibc thing, not a gcc thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236159/linux-command-file-shows-for-gnu-linux-2-6-24

Comment: @Shawn How can glibc matter when the binary is statically linked?

Comment: It's statically linked to a particular version of glibc, which in turn was configured to require a particular minimum kernel version.

Comment: @Shawn Why is it glibc instead of binutils (`as`, `ld` etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specify the expected Linux version of the output binary of GCC

in your question you speak about the version of libc C but that can also concerns a lot of other libs, and may be you want also produce 32b and/or 64b executable(s).

For me the most secure way is to use *pbuilder*, I use it to produce [BoUML](https://bouml.fr/download.html#Ubuntu)  *debs* for Ubuntu Cosmic (18.10) Bionic (18.04), Artful (17.10) Zesty (17.04) Yakkety (16.10) Xenial (16.04) Trusty (14.04) and Precise (12.04) and that in both 32b and 64b, and I do all of that from my Ubuntu Xenial 64b just doing the appropriate sequence of *pbuilder* commands (without any reboot to go in each Linux release)

That needs time to generate a version but because this is made in the corresponding Linux version you are sure of the result.

Answer (score 0):

The provided lab environment was Ubuntu 14.04, where the package *libc6* has version `2.19-0ubuntu6.14`.

The lab instruction provided by the teaching *assistants* contained an instruction to change the APT source by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually, which had a SERIOUS disaster in it: The "version" string in the edited example was **xenial** instead of **trusty**, which, if followed, would *factually* update your system to Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04). The new version of *libc6* was `2.23-0ubuntu11`, which would cause `as` and `ld` (from binutils, not related to GCC) to output ELF with a minimum Linux version of 2.6.32.

With glibc version 2.19, the output ELF is compatible with Linux 2.6.24, but with glibc 2.23, the output is only compatible with Linux 2.6.32.

I tested and verified this by compiling a test program under Ubuntu 14.04 and checking the ELF information, then replaced all `trusty` with `xenial`, did `apt-get update` and **only** updated `binutils` and its dependencies (which includes libc6), and compiled the program and checked it again.